# Extract values and Package Ping JAVA

Tags: java, ping

I need help, i have this code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    JavaApplication2 ping = new JavaApplication2();
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("ping");
    commands.add("-n");
    commands.add("3");
    commands.add("10.40.1.156");
    ping.doCommand(commands);
}

public void doCommand(List<String> command) throws IOException {
    String s = null;
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**And this is my output**

Here is the standard output of the command:

> Haciendo ping a 10.40.1.156 con 32 bytes de datos:
>
> Respuesta desde 10.40.1.156: bytes=32 tiempo=2ms TTL=255
>
> Respuesta desde 10.40.1.156: bytes=32 tiempo=2ms TTL=255
>
> Respuesta desde 10.40.1.156: bytes=32 tiempo=87ms TTL=255
>
> Estad�sticas de ping para 10.40.1.156:
>
> ```
> Paquetes: enviados = 3, recibidos = 3, perdidos = 0
>
> (0% perdidos),
> ```
>
> Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
>
> ```
> M�nimo = 2ms, M�ximo = 87ms, Media = 30ms
> ```

Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

**But i need only the seconds and the Packages**

Comment: As your output is in a non-English language, do you care to explain a bit more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: There are a few ways to approach this problem: 1) read the manpage for ping `man ping` and see if you can pass arguments to ping to only show the data you want OR 2) Parse the output you get from ping to get the packets and time. Consider using `java.lang.String' methods or Apache Commons String Utils OR 3) using a java network package to do the ping instead of calling the command

Comment: @AbdulFatir The OP is trying to have java execute the `ping` command and wants to parse its output to retrieve the statistics on the packets and the latency. the output shown is that of a standard execution of `ping`

Comment: In that case I suggest to do the `ping` using code rather than using a process to the **ping.exe** because even if you use a hardcoded substring() you cannot be always sure of the output the `ping` returns.

Comment: i want only "Paquetes: enviados = 3, recibidos = 3, perdidos = 0" and "M�nimo = 2ms, M�ximo = 87ms, Media = 30ms"